# How can I find a node in HTML which has marked-up text by searching for the plaintext?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm trying to find the "closest" nodes in a HTML document that holds in its innertext a specific string using xpath or javascript (node) libraries; in a HTML snippet like

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet, <em>{cons</em>ectetur} adipiscing elit.</strong> Morbi rhoncus lacinia orci a dapibus. Nulla facilisi. Sed id nibh ornare, aliquet ante nec, efficitur leo. Sed viverra ex turpis,</p>
```

if I'm looking for words that match `{cons.*tur}`, so in this case `{consectetur}`, I want to find the `<strong>` node rather than the `<p>` node because that's the smallest node that has it.

edit: the `strong` here is just an example, it could be any tagName, and it could be deeply nested; the word I'm looking for could also be spread out over more than two nesting levels as in the example above.

more edit: I'm actually looking for a pattern, so an `//div[contains(., 'consectetur')]` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I'm looking for words that match `{cons.*tur}`, so in this case
>   `{consectetur}`, I want to find the `<strong>` node rather than the `<p>`
>   node because that's the smallest node that has it.

You need an expression that select the last descendant element that has a string value matching your pattern. So

```
/descendant::*[contains(.,'{consectetur}')][last()]
```

If there would be more than one of this element (different branch) to select, then you will need an expression selecting and element matching your pattern with no descendant also matching it.

```
//*[contains(.,'{consectetur}') and not(.//*[contains(.,'{consectetur}'])]
```

### About then pattern

If you want to use regular expression you need at least XPath 2.0 [functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#string.match). Your current pattern `{cons.*tur}` in XPath 1.0 is the same as

```
contains(substring-after(.,'{cons'),'tur}')
```

Comment: But that would search for the exact term, correct? I'm looking for instances of a regex pattern.

There would typically be more than one, probably at different nesting levels in the document.

Comment: I've left the pattern out because the problem is about how to select the minimum container.

Comment: That's half the problem in my case. But it's true that this solution could well be part of the full solution. edit: I could find all patterns in the plaintect by just looking for those using body.textContent and apply your solution. I'll test, if that works, I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: I'm getting an xpath parse error when I try `const nodes = xpath.select("//*[contains(.,'{consectetur}') and not(.//*[contains(.,'{consectetur}'])]", doc)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.textContent` property to extract the text from a tag.

```js
const str = document.querySelector('body *:not(script)').textContent;
console.log(str);

const rgx = /consectetur/g;

let res = rgx.exec(str);
while (res !== null) {
  console.log(res[0]);
  res = rgx.exec(str);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet, <em>cons</em>ectetur adipiscing elit.</strong> Morbi rhoncus lacinia orci a dapibus. Nulla facilisi. Sed id nibh ornare, aliquet ante nec, efficitur leo. Sed viverra ex turpis,</p>
```

Comment: I don't know where in the text the word will live, or what the tagName of the enclosing node would be, it could well be in a deeply nested spot -- I can of course get the text content of the entire document and find the string, but how do I relate that back to its location in a node?

Comment: after the edit that will get me the text but not the enclosing node. I need the enclosing node.