# Search all occurrences a string only when the nodes are children of a specific node containing an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider this example:

```
<foo attr1="dummy">
   <bar1>
     some text #{abc} some text
   </bar1>
   <bar2>
     <bar2bar2>
        some text #{def} some text
     </bar2bar2>
   </bar2>
</foo>
```

I need an XPath 1.0 query (which doesn't support regex) that search for all occurrences of **# {*}** when the nodes are (direct or indirect) children of a node **foo** with attribute **attr1**. In other words, the query should return:

```
some text #{abc} some other text
some text #{def} some other text
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answering the original question): Try the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//text()[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'#{') and substring(normalize-space(.),string-length(normalize-space(.)),1)='}' and  ancestor::foo[@attr1]]
```

It returns the desired `text()` nodes, but with leading and trailing spaces. This cannot be avoided in XPath-1.0, because the `normalize-space()` function only takes one argument. In XPath-2.0 you could simply add `/normalize-space()` to the end of the expression to handle that.

Comment: Thanks. This works for my original question (I modified it now), when occurrences of ${*} stand alone. But I made a question a bit wrong, I actually want to match a regular expression. So the # {*} may be in between some text. Is there any way to fix it to capture those cases.

Comment: In XPath-1.0, there is no possibility to apply a RegEx. What comes closest is using two `contains(...)`. So the following is only a good approximation: `//text()[contains(.,'#{') and contains(substring-after(.,'#{'),'}') and  ancestor::foo[@attr1]]`.

Comment: Just for completeness and if you'll find a way to use XPath-2.0: `//text()[matches(.,'.*#\{.*\}.*') and  ancestor::foo[@attr1]]` satisfies all conditions best.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an XPath 1.0 query (which doesn't support regex) that search
>   for all occurrences of **#{*}** when the nodes are (direct or indirect)
>   children of a node **foo** with attribute **attr1**. In other words, the query
>   should return

```
//foo//text()[contains(.,'#{')][contains(substring-after(.,'#{'),'}')]
```

**Do note** that this expression will select text nodes. If you have mixed content (elements having text and marckup like HTML `p`'s having `em` or `span`) then the string is going to be split in several text nodes. For that you will need something like this answer: [How can I find a node in HTML which has marked-up text by searching for the plaintext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183375/how-can-i-find-a-node-in-html-which-has-marked-up-text-by-searching-for-the-plai/55191618#55191618)